# TestNG and Selenium- IE fails to launch independent threads

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, testng

I'm using TestNG and Selenium to perform parallel tests. This works great in Firefox and Chrome, but breaks in IE. The steps I have the web driver executing are as follow:

1. A browser instance is created using a parameter from testng.xml (found below)
2. An available user is selected from a pool of test user credentials
3. The user is logged in
4. Tests proceed

When IE launches its instances, all of them are assigned the same user. Furthermore, all instances appear to fight over which one has focus. (Conversely, in Firefox and Chrome, all instances are appropriately assigned their own user and do not fight over focus.)

Because each IE instance uses the same user credentials, I get testing collisions and because they fight over which instance has focus, I get Selenium TimeoutExceptions due to waitForElementPresent commands.

My hunch is that IE is simply incapable of having multiple unique instances open concurrently. Can anyone either confirm my suspicion or direct me as to how I might remedy the issue? Thank you for your help!!

For reference, here is my testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="6" verbose="0" name="Command line suite" parallel="tests">

    <!-- IE Tests -->
    <test name="SourceBoxUIIe" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.familysearch.links.uitests.SourceBoxUITest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="EditPageIe" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.familysearch.links.uitests.EditPageUITest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="LinksGadgetPageIe" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.familysearch.links.uitests.LinksGadgetPageUITest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="AdminChangeLogIe" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.familysearch.links.uitests.AdminChangeLogPageUITest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="AttachedToPageIe" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.familysearch.links.uitests.AttachedToPageUITest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="ChangeLogIe" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.familysearch.links.uitests.ChangeLogUITest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!-- Firefox Tests Would Be here -->
    <!-- Chrome Tests Would Be Here-->

  <!-- Command line test -->
</suite> <!-- Command line suite -->
```

Comment: are you using xpath for the majority of your selectors? IE seems to have a great deal of problems when it comes to speed with xpath selectors. That's why i migrated entirely over to CSS

Comment: Thank you for your response. We're using id and class tags whenever possible. Could using xpath prevent IE from having simultaneous login sessions?

Comment: many of the issues i ran into were consistently speed, and locators.  Sometimes it couldn't find an input with an id of "username", sometimes it couldn't.. it was very interesting.  Never a problem with simultaneous login though per se.

Comment: That could be useful. Perhaps when it gives a TimeoutException, it's simply because it fails to locate the DOM element. That'll be difficult for me to implement without the UI team adding CSS tags for me to hook, but I'll look into it. Thanks again for the thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch is almost correct. Per the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) :

*Multiple instances of InternetExplorerDriver*

With the creation of the IEDriverServer.exe, it should be possible to create and use multiple simultaneous instances of the InternetExplorerDriver. **However, this functionality is largely untested, and there may be issues with cookies, window focus, and the like. If you attempt to use multiple instances of the IE driver, and run into such issues, consider using the RemoteWebDriver and virtual machines.**

There are 2 solutions for problem with cookies (and another session items) shared between multiple instances of InternetExplorer.

The first is to start your InternetExplorer in private mode. After that InternetExplorer will be started with clean session data and will not save changed session data at quitting. To do so you need to pass 2 specific capabilities to driver: ie.forceCreateProcessApi with true value and ie.browserCommandLineSwitches with -private value. Be aware that it will work only for InternetExplorer 8 and newer, and Windows Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main path should contain key TabProcGrowth with 0 value.

The second is to clean session during InternetExplorer starting. For this you need to pass specific ie.ensureCleanSession capability with true value to driver. This clears the cache for all running instances of InternetExplorer, including those started manually.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely specific tips. Our development servers are down for some maintenance at the moment, but I'll absolutely try this when they come back online and comment again with the results.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I spent a lot of time looking into this and your answer is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I attempted to implement what you suggested exactly, but was unable to get `ie.forceCreateProcessApi` and `ie.browserCommandLineSwitches` enabled. After trying for a bit, I instead went with `setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true)` and `setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private")`. Are these the same thing?

Comment: @JPod Yes, these should be the same.