# Selenium grid issue on 5 internet explorer parallel execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

i am working on a large application and it is passing when run on one Internet explorer
But when lunched on 2 or more threads on same machine using selenium grid and Testng. one test case passing and other failing. how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG and Selenium- IE fails to launch independent threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504074/testng-and-selenium-ie-fails-to-launch-independent-threads)

Comment: i tried stilll failing

Answer (score 0):

Check your driver instantiation access modifier. If your not using Protected give that try. This has resolved threading issues for me in the past.